# Armazenamento em array

Tags: c, array

tenho uma duvida sobre o armazenamento de informações em array, eu pensava que, quando dentro de um loop, uma array de tamanho 200, por exemplo `char nome[200]`
ela seria preenchida continuamente até que não sobrace mais espaço para guardar a informação, fazendo com que o sistema retornasse um erro, mas em alguns exemplos que eu tenho feito, a array é reutilizada no loop e ao invés de ser "completada" no espaço que ela ainda tem, parece que o espaço que foi usado tem a informação substituída, se isso realmente acontece, por que a array não é completada?

```
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char ch;
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char abc[200];
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        while( (ch = getchar() != '\n') && ch != EOF);
        fgets( abc,200,stdin);
        length = strlen( abc);
        printf("%d", length);
        printf("%s", abc);
    }
}
```

este é um exemplo. se eu digitar uma frase de tamanho 100 e depois outra de tamanho 100 a segunda ira passar a ocupar o lugar da primeira, ao invés de completar os outros 100 que restava? e se eu digitar uma de tamanho 200 e depois outra de tamanho 100, ocorrerá a substituição?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nunca tem espaço vazio em uma array. Quando você declara `char abc[200];`, cada um dos 200 `char`s dentro dessa array possui algum valor desconhecido.

Pela [especificação da linguagem C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (que é o documento que descreve oficialmente a linguagem C, publicado pela [ISO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Internacional_para_Padroniza%C3%A7%C3%A3o)), quando um array é declarado desta forma, como uma variável local, seu valor inicial ou não é especificado, ou é um valor especial chamado de *trap representation*, que não deve ser lido nem utilizado no programa. Na prática, a sua array `abc` vai conter, de início, o valor que por acaso já estiver na região de memória que o compilador reservar para a variável. O importante a ter em mente é: não existe o conceito de variável "vazia" na linguagem C, portanto não faz sentido falar em "completar o array".

No seu código, quando você chama `fgets(abc, 200, stdin);`, todas as informações que `fgets` tem foi o que você passou: `abc`, `200` e `stdin`. No seu laço `for` você chama `fgets` exatamente do mesmo jeito por `n` vezes, e portanto ele vai se comportar da mesma maneira todas as vezes, escrevendo a string a partir do início do array `abc`.

Quando você passa um array para uma função que recebe um ponteiro, como é o caso do primeiro parâmetro de `fgets()`, o que você passa é na verdade o endereço de memória do primeiro elemento do array. Portanto, os dois códigos abaixo são equivalentes:

```
fgets( abc,200,stdin);
```

e

```
fgets(&abc[0],200,stdin);
```

Se você quer que a string seja escrita em abc a partir de uma dada posição `k` ≤ 200, você deve chamá-lo com:

```
fgets(&abc[k], 200 - k, stdin);
```

Por que `200 - k` no segundo argumento? Porque o segundo argumento diz quantas posições a partir do endereço dado no primeiro argumento a função `fgets()` pode utilizar. Se você está escrevendo a partir da posição `k`, só existem `200 - k` posições a partir dali.

Comment: Excelente! obrigado pela explicação.